# Kendo color picker in kendo grid editor template throws error when gird column data contains named color

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-colorpicker

The Kendo Color Picker in Kendo Grid Editor Template throws parsing error when gird column data contains named color. It works perfectly fine when the column has hexadecimal value.

Following is the code for the column for which the editor template is invoked

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<SomeViewModel>()
              .Name("grdSomeDataGrid")
              .Columns(c => {
                              ...
                              c.Bound(n => n.ColorValue)
                               .ClientTemplate("<span style='display: inline-block; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #= ImageColor #'>&nbsp;</span>")
                              ...
                            })
```

Following is my editor template code

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI

@(Html.Kendo().ColorPicker()
              .Name("ColorValue"))
```

Comment: The [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/colorpicker#methods-value) states that you need to pass in a string in _hex, rgb or rgba_ format or an object of type [`kendo.Color`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/color).

Comment: You can use any css class and add that to the span in clientTemplate. Refer that css in your corresponding view.

Comment: @AndreiV But the named values works perfectly fine here. Please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4g359wyr/

Comment: Hmm... Ok, point taken. What's the actual error then?

Comment: For e.g. "Cannot parse color: PURPLE"